# Convert to UTF8

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, ascii, encoder

I manage a cms in which users can leave comments, today one of the comments could not be added because a modsecurity rule jumped.

Locate the comment to restore it, in what format is it? I have tried to convert it in various ways to UTF8 but have not succeeded

Example text

> Disclaimer%3a+Mi+perspectiva+es+bastante+negativa%2e+Tened+en+cuenta+que+es+subjetiva+y+que+conozco+a+gente+que+s%c3%ad+ha+estado+contenta+con+la+carrera%2e+Todo+es+presuntamente+y+de+acuerdo+a+mi+facultad%2c+mis+profesores+y+mi+experiencia%2e+%2d%2d%2d%0d%0a%0d%0a1%2e%09INTRODUCCI%c3%93N%3a%0d%0aEscog%c3%ad+la+Universidad+de+C%c3%a1diz+por+cercan%c3%ada+y+porque+es+una+de+las+pocas+universidades+de+Espa%c3%b1a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's URL Encoding (Percent Encoding) [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

You can use [this](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/) to decode/encode it

Comment: Thanks the decode worked properly. I tried it on other websites and this was the last one, you saved me

Comment: @Diego no problem